# Pulling column values from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to get all the values (numeric) of the column Bruel_ID from database mpctz_rsform_bruels to display them in a RSForm dropdown box. I'm using this code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT Bruel_ID FROM mpctz_rsform_bruels");
return $db->loadResult();
```

Howeve, I am only pulling the lowest value of the column. How can I get all the values?
Thanks,

Dani

Edit: I have been searching and I've found this code which was supposed to work:

```
//<code>
// Prepare the empty array
$items = array();
// Prepare the database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Keep this if you'd like a "Please select" option, otherwise comment or remove it
$items[] = "|Selecciona un número[c]";

// Run the SQL query and store it in $results
$db->setQuery("SELECT Bruel_ID, Bruel_ID FROM #__rsform_bruels");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

// Now, we need to convert the results into a readable RSForm! Pro format.
// The Items field will accept values in this format:
// value-to-be-stored|value-to-be-shown
// Eg. m|M-sized T-shirt
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $value = $result->your_value;
  $label = $result->your_label;
  $items[] = $value.'|'.$label;
}

// Multiple values are separated by new lines, so we need to do this now
$items = implode("\n", $items);

// Now we need to return the value to the field
return $items;
//</code>
```

However, it displays nothing in the dropdown box, just the default value. Any help?

Comment: That is the proper query.

Comment: I'm quite new to PHP and MySQL and I maybe missing something. Actually, I need the query to pull all the rows from Bruel_ID column in mpctz_rsform_bruels. What's what I am missing?

Comment: Show us the code that creates the dropdown.

Comment: I don't have the code Nikolas, it is a default by RSForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loadColumn()` to get an array of all the result in a single column. The below shows just that and a `foreach` loop so that each result displays on a new line:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('Bruel_ID'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_bruels'))
      ->order($db->quoteName('Bruel_ID') . 'DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadColumn();

$items[] = "|Selecciona un número[c]";

foreach ($results as $id) {
    $items[] = $id.'|'.$id;
}

$items = implode("\n", $items);

return $items;
```

This uses the most up to date Joomla coding standards for a database query.

Also notice I have replaced `mpctz_` with `#__` which is a built in Joomla feature that will automatically get the table prefix. It saves you having to manually define it which is bad as in the future, you may decide to change the prefixx.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lodder for your answer. Indeed it displays the values but outside the dropdown box. See my edited original question for further info. Also, thanks for explaining the suffix change. Great value!

Comment: @DaniValverde - Just seen your edit. Wasn't aware you required a dropdown. I've updated my answer which will display a dropdown selectbox with the results

Comment: Thanks Lodder. That's not exactly what I need. Have a loot at the site http://apnae.t15.org/index.php/que-fem/el-bruel. At the bottom you'll see the dropdown box. This is a predefined dropdown box from RSForms which I need to fill using some PHP code (see my edited question). Your code works great, except that it adds its own dropbox, so I end up having 2 dropboxes.

Comment: @DaniValverde - I'm not sure exactly how RSForms works in regards to populating things, however I've merged my code with the code in your question. Have a test and see the results.

Comment: You're great Lodder! It works!! Just a question. How can I sort the values descending?

Comment: @DaniValverde - I've updated my code with the descending order feature ;)

Comment: Lodder, could you please have a look at an other thread of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116199/populating-a-field-with-values-from-another-field I don't know how to handle it. Thank you so much!