# Populating a field with values from another field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm quite new with PHP and javascript, so apologize me if this is an easy question.I have a form with a dropdown box and a GO button, used to select documents (from the dropdown box) and navigate to them (GO button). What I would like to do is to retrieve the document URL from the database when the dropdown item is selected and pass it to the button, so when clicked it sends the user to the document. The MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT `Bruel_URL` FROM `mpctz_rsform_bruels` WHERE `Bruel_ID` = GO.value
```

So the questions are:

1. How do I get the value from the `Bruel_ID` and pass it to the MySQL query (I've represented it as GO.value in the query above)?
2. How do I retrieve and store the `Bruel_URL`?
3. How can I write a javascript function that sends the user to the `Bruel_URL`?
   Thanks for your help!

Dani

Comment: I will post an answer for this later on, however please read the documentation and start step by step. I would also think about another/better approach. Start with connecting to the database, and getting the value using some of the code I provided in my previous answer for you ;)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it's the simpliest way just PHP redirect without javascript.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    <select name="document">
        <option value="1">Document 1</option>
        <option value="2">Document 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['document'])){
    // using PDO connection
    // select row
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `Bruel_URL` as url FROM `mpctz_rsform_bruels` WHERE `Bruel_ID` = :document_id');
    $stmt->bindValue(':document_id', $_POST['document']. PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // if url exists - redirect
    if(!empty($row['url'])){
        header('Location:'.$row['url']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would put the form at the end, so it only shows when there is no redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! As I said, I'm a newbie on PHP, where should I place the code?

Comment: Copy, paste, edit to your requiremenents and connect to database PDO

Comment: This is  a Joomla question, not raw PHP ;)